# undefined reference to `strnstr' how to fix it and run strnstr

Tags: c, gcc, string.h

I need to reproduce behavior of `strnstr` function. I want to test `strnstr` but can't compile program, its written `"implicit declaration of function strnstr [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]"` and `"undefined reference to strnstr"`. I included header `<string.h>`.

I know that `strnstr()` isn't in standard library and the problem is probably connected with compiler, but how to fix it to work with `strnstr()`?

**Compiler version: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609**

Comment: Don't tell us what you tried, show us what you tried.

Comment: It's a BSD function, so it's typically not available in Linux with GCC. Either re-implement it, or rewrite the code that uses it do something differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no function named `strnstr` in standard C or POSIX. It's not in glibc/Linux either.
It appears to be [FreeBSD function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strnstr&sektion=3).

> I know that strnstr() isn't in standard library and the problem is probably connected with compiler, but how to fix it to work with strnstr()?

Not sure why you think it's a compiler issue (unless you think it's a compiler intrinsic). If it's not provided by your C library, it's just not available.

So if it's not available on your system (probably you are not using a BSD system) then you can implement it. You can look at an [existing implementation](https://github.com/lattera/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/string/strnstr.c).